# Indian movie censorship guideline

Tags: censorship, indian-cinema

I know few things which are restricted in Indian movies:

- Showing the face of president
- Showing that the prime minister is corrupt.

Are there any other things that a creator of a movie has to avoid? Are the Indian censorship guidelines available online somewhere?

Comment: FWIW, this question, in my opinion, definitely is NOT too localized. Despite being linked to a geographic region, the region in question is about 300% more populous than the US.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **simple** Google search led me to the [Guidelines of Central Board of Film Certification.](http://cbfcindia.gov.in/html/uniquepage.aspx?unique_page_id=1)

The article states:

> The Cinematograph Act lays down that a film shall not be certified if
>   any part of it is against the interest of the sovereignty and
>   integrity of India, the security of the State, friendly relations with
>   foreign States, public order, decency or involves defamation or
>   contempt of court or is likely to incite commission of any offence.
>   Under section 5B(2) the Central Government has issued the following
>   guidelines.
>
> A film is judged in its entirety from the point of view of its overall
>   impact and is examined in the light of the period depicted in the film
>   and the contemporary standards of the country and the people to whom
>   the film relates, provided that the film does not deprave the morality
>   of the audience. Guidelines are applied to the titles of the films
>   also.
>
> 1. Objectives of Film Certification i)    the medium of film remains responsible and sensitive to the values and standards of
>      society; ii)   artistic expression and creative freedom are not unduly
>      curbed; iii)  certification is responsible to social changes; iv)  the
>      medium of film provides clean and healthy entertainment; and v)   as
>      far as possible, the film is of aesthetic value and cinematically of a
>      good standard.
> 2. In pursuance of the above objectives, the CBFC shall ensure that   i)      anti social activities such as violence are not
>      glorified or justified ii)      the modus operandi of criminals, other
>      visuals or words likely to incite the commission of any offence are
>      not depicted; iii)     scenes - a.  showing involvement of children in
>      violence as victims or perpetrators or as forced witnesses to
>      violence, or showing children as being subjected to any form of child
>      abuse. b.   showing abuse or ridicule of physically and mentally
>      handicapped persons; and c. showing cruelty to, or abuse of animals,
>      are not presented needlessly iv)     pointless or avoidable scenes of
>      violence, cruelty and horror, scenes of violence primarily intended to
>      provide entertainment and such scenes as may have the effect of
>      de-sensitising or de-humanising people are not shown; v)      scenes
>      which have the effect of justifying or glorifying drinking are not
>      shown; vi)     scenes tending to encourage, justify or glamorise drug
>      addiction are not shown; a.   scenes tending to encourage, justify or
>      glamorise consumption of tobacco or smoking are not shown; vii)
>      human sensibilities are not offended by vulgarity, obscenity or
>      depravity; viii)   such dual meaning words as obviously cater to baser
>      instincts are not allowed; ix)     scenes degrading or denigrating
>      women in any manner are not presented; x)      scenes involving sexual
>      violence against women like attempt to rape, rape or any form of
>      molestation or scenes of a similar nature are avoided, and if any such
>      incidence is germane to the theme, they shall be reduced to the
>      minimum and no details are shown xi)     scenes showing sexual
>      perversions shall be avoided and if such matters are germane to the
>      theme they shall be reduced to the minimum and no details are shown
>      xii)     visuals or words contemptuous of racial, religious or other
>      groups are not presented xiii)    visuals or words which promote
>      communal, obscurantist, anti-scientific and anti-national attitude are
>      not presented xiv)    the sovereignty and integrity of India is not
>      called in question; xv)     the security of the State is not
>      jeopardized or endangered xvi)    friendly relations with foreign
>      States are not strained; xvii)   public order is not endangered xviii)
>      visuals or words involving defamation of an individual or a body of
>      individuals, or contempt of court are not presented   EXPLANATION:
>      Scenes that tend to create scorn, disgrace or disregard of rules or
>      undermine the dignity of court will come under the term ''Contempt of
>      Court'' : and   xix)   national symbols and emblems are not shown
>      except in accordance with the provisions of the Emblems and Names
>      (Prevention of Improper Use) Act, 1950 (12 of 1950)
> 3. The Board of Film Certification shall also ensure that the film i)    Is judged in its entirety from the point of view of its
>      overall impact; and ii)   Is examined in the light of the period
>      depicted in the films and the contemporary standards of the country
>      and the people to which the film relates provided that the film does
>      not deprave the morality of the audience.
> 4. Films that meet the above – mentioned criteria but are considered unsuitable for exhibition to non-adults shall be certified
>      for exhibition to adult audiences only.
> 5. i)    While certifying films for unrestricted public exhibition, the Board shall ensure that the film is suitable for
>      family viewing, that is to say, the film shall be such that all the
>      members of the family including children can view it together. ii)
>      If the Board, having regard to the nature, content and theme of the
>      film is of the opinion that it is necessary to caution the parents /
>      guardian to consider as to whether any child below the age of twelve
>      years maybe allowed to see such a film, the film shall be certified
>      for unrestricted public exhibition with an endorsement to that effect.
>      iii)   If the Board having regard to the nature, content and theme of
>      the film, is of the opinion that the exhibition of the film should be
>      restricted to members of any profession or any class of persons, the
>      film shall be certified for public exhibition restricted to the
>      specialized audiences to be specified by the Board in this behalf.
> 6. The Board shall scrutinize the titles of the films carefully and ensure that they are not provocative, vulgar, offensive or violative
>      of any of the above-mentioned guidelines.